# Store and retrieve theme choice from localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have created a test web page to enable a choice of three different themes using `onclick="document.body.className"` buttons. These work as expected but the choice is not saved on refresh.

I would like to store and retrieve a user's choice from localstorage. As I am approaching 80 years, I'm too old to start learning JavaScript so would very much appreciate help with a working script.

If this is possible, I will apply this feature to all my club's webpages. The test page is at: http://12phillipstreet.com/alternative-themes.html

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to request written software.  If you have _specific_ questions we can answer those.  Put another way, we don't build people cars.  But we do tell people how to fix or enhance them.

Comment: You've come to the wrong place, we don't program for free. You should ask questions to problem that you are solving and you must show a minimal solution to your problem that we can tip you on where it's failing. You don't seem interested in learning Javascript, so hire a programmer.

Comment: There are rules, and then there is wisdom in applying the rules.  I don't agree the question doesn't belong here, and I'm glad to see someone provided an answer.

Comment: @dave There are rules, and one of them specifies that questions like this do not belong here.

Comment: @Jonas92 I have spent hundreds of voluntary hours over many years creating and maintaining a website for a senior citizens computer club. My desire has always been to provide better access for our physically and visually disabled users. If my request for help related to this mission has contravened the rules of this forum, please accept my sincere apology.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

```
<div class="button-new"><label for="theme">Themes:</label>
    <button class="white" type="submit">.</button>
    <button class="khaki" type="submit">.</button>
    <button class="black" type="submit">.</button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var body = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
function retrieveClass(){
    var getClass = localStorage.getItem("changeThemeClass") || "tw";
    body.className=getClass;
}
function changeTheme(elem, cls){
    document.getElementsByClassName(elem)[0].onclick=function(){
        body.className=cls;
        localStorage.setItem("changeThemeClass", cls);
    };
}
retrieveClass();
changeTheme("white", "tw");
changeTheme("khaki", "tk");
changeTheme("black", "tb");
```

Comment: Avril, Thanks for your quick reply and code - it all looks good to me. However, although I think I installed it correctly, the chosen theme does not appear to be saved to local-storage or show on page refresh. I have tested it using current Chrome, FF, IE and Safari browsers, each giving the same result. Still I believe your code is certainly heading in the right direction and perhaps a few tweaks are all that is needed. Thanks again. jl

Comment: add `retriveClass();` call function.

Comment: Avril, Unfortunately adding retriveClass(); at 4th line from the bottom always defaults to the black theme on refresh no matter which colour is selected.  At least it shows the local-storage is working so that's a positive - thanks for that. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Avril, You are indeed a genius. Your code now works brilliantly and switches between the three alternative colour themes instantly. I now need only one css file which incorporates the three theme styles to achieve this. Previously I needed four css files to do the same thing.

Comment: Avril, Thank you for sharing your expertise so generously.